# How to create a pannable real-time chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I'm using `react-chart-2` with `chartjs-plugin-zoom` and `chartjs-plugin-streaming` plugins. Now I'm showing the last 20 data points in the chart. I want to modify this to `pannable` chart.

```
    const [sensorReadings, setSensorReadings] = useState();
       
    useEffect(()=>{
       // code for fetch initial readings from back end
    },[]);
    datasets: [
       {
           backgroundColor: colors.indigo[500],
           data: sensorReadings.map(reading => ({ x: reading.time, y: reading.value })),
           label: 'This year',
           fill: false
       }
   ]
```

This is my datasets object. Here the sensor readings object will have last 20 readings. When a user scrolls the charts (scrolls to the older date), I want to trigger a function say `fetchRest()`, that will fetch the next 20 readings and update the state.
My question is how to trigger that `fetchRest`, when a user scrolls?

**Edited**

This is similar to blog post page, where at the beginning we display only certain amount of posts and when the user reaches the bottom of the page, we fetch next set of posts and display them.

Answer (score 1):

The chartjs-plugin-zoom provide an event listeners for user `"onPan"` interaction. You can access them here https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-zoom/guide/options.html#pan-events

So the ideas is to call fetchRest() on user pan, so you can attach your function call, in the event listener, like :

```js
pan: {
   onPan: function(chart){
      fetchRest() //fetch call
   }
},
```

Comment: This onPan function will call each and every time a pan event trigger. But my requirement is to call that function when ever user reaches that other edge only.

Comment: If other edge means your latest fetch data, you could add a condition before calling the fetchRest(), something like if(chart scrolled all the way to edge), or chart xAxis scroll value, or if last data is showed. Remember that you had access to current chart parameter value from the onPan function callback

Comment: My question is how to find that 'chart scrolled all the way to edge' condition. I know i can get the current scroll value from chart object. But how to check if that value exceeds my current value (something like current chart width)?

Comment: can you help to provide a working jsfiddle ?

Comment: I've tried with stackblitz.com. Can you check it out? https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-f5czwt?file=src%2FChart.js